# When does sync say yes on polkadot-js UI?

Tags: polkadot-js

[image: polkadot UI]

This maybe a trivial question:

As you can see here this is my local node that imports some 300 blocks and I was expecting this syncing to say `yes` instead of `no`. When does it say yes?  I am running with `pruning=archive` and also tried running with `prunig=1000` to see if it made a difference but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The display there is from the `system_health` RPC which returns a [Health struct](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/994bb57b77b2845e9e1b48d8eb77c9160366d525/client/rpc-api/src/system/helpers.rs#L43-L52).

This itself is populated from the [networking sync state](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/994bb57b77b2845e9e1b48d8eb77c9160366d525/client/service/src/lib.rs#L187-L192). The value finally comes from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/994bb57b77b2845e9e1b48d8eb77c9160366d525/client/network/src/protocol/sync.rs#L605-L618) on the networking layer.

The logic in this code seems to indicate that when current the connected height is [5 blocks](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/994bb57b77b2845e9e1b48d8eb77c9160366d525/client/network/src/protocol/sync.rs#L104) behind, it is in sync state.